# How do I make a nested json schema in Marshmallow?

Tags: python, json, marshmallow

I am trying to take data from a table in SQL Server and convert it to a JSON format. I achieved conversion to a rudimentary JSON format using Marshmallow. I have not worked with JSON extensively. The requirement is to convert it into a hierarchical JSON format like shown below:

Required JSON format:

```
 {
        "Year" : [{
            "2016" : [{
                "Q1" : [{
                    "Jan" : [{
                        "Week1" : [{
                            "Sunday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Monday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Tuesday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Wednesday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Thursday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Friday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Saturday" : [1,2,3]
                        }],
                        "Week2" : [{
                            "Sunday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Monday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Tuesday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Wednesday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Thursday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Friday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Saturday" : [1,2,3]
                        }],
                        "Week3" : [{
                            "Sunday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Monday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Tuesday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Wednesday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Thursday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Friday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Saturday" : [1,2,3]
                        }],
                        "Week4" : [{
                            "Sunday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Monday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Tuesday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Wednesday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Thursday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Friday" : [1,2,3],
                            "Saturday" : [1,2,3]
                        }],
                    }],
                }],
            }],
        }],
    }
```

I have read data from table, created some functions and have achieved this format:

Sample achieved format:

```
[{"sent_year": 2017, "sent_quarter": 4, "sent_month": "December", "sent_week": "Week5", "sent_day": "Sunday", "application_name": "App Two", "sent_score": "3"},
 {"sent_year": 2017, "sent_quarter": 4, "sent_month": "December", "sent_week": "Week5", "sent_date": "Monday", "application_name": "App One", "sent_score": "1"}, 
 {"sent_year": 2017, "sent_quarter": 4, "sent_month": "December", "sent_week": "Week5", "sent_date": "Tuesday", "application_name": "App Two", "sent_score": "3"},
 {"sent_year": 2016, "sent_quarter": 4, "sent_month": "December", "sent_week": "Week5", "sent_date": "Wednesday", "application_name": "App One", "sent_score": "2"}, 
 {"sent_year": 2016, "sent_quarter": 4, "sent_month": "December", "sent_week": "Week5", "sent_date": "Thursday", "application_name": "App Two", "sent_score": "1"}, 
 {"sent_year": 2016, "sent_quarter": 4, "sent_month": "December", "sent_week": "Week5", "sent_date": "Friday", "application_name": "App One", "sent_score": "4"}]
```

Since this involves grouping of data based on values, I'm unable to figure out how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: how `sent_score` to be calculated from above JSON?

Comment: `sent_score` is already available in the database and I have brought it to the above mentioned JSON format. Now `sent_score` must be grouped based on day of the week which will based on week of the month and so on.

Comment: so you can iterate over list and can create dictionary containing list

Comment: Looks like you are trying to group rows based on some columns value which is not what Marshmallow is for.

Comment: Oh ok. Can you suggest how this grouping can be done? I am having issues since this has layers of data, i.e., I have to groupby year and then by quarter and so on.